# Django: Concatenate two manytomany fields in one single field and save it in the database

Tags: django, django-models, django-related-manager

I have these two models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_info = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project_manager = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name="project_manager")
    project_collaborator = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name="project_collaborator")
```

I want to save in the database the field "project_info" with this concatenated value: "project_manager & project_collaborator".

I tried to override the save method of the Project model:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.project_info = self.project_manager + '&' + self.project_collaborator
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but it returns me the error "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'ManyRelatedManager' and 'str'".

Comment: Why would you do that? You can simply get the items when necessary through querying.

Comment: Hi WilleM, thanks for the answer. I thought about that. I'm studying Django and database in general and I thought that the most long term secure approach was to save directly to the database rather than getting it from the query.

Comment: storing it explicitly will likely make it *less* secure. Indeed, now each time you update the `project_manager`, etc. you need to sync who has access, so that means if you revoke access to somone, it might be possible that a view does not update the field, and therefore the person still has access.

Answer (score 1):

I would not save this as a separate field in the database, since it's already implicitly available on the model itself.

Three things:

1. related_name is the name of the reverse attribute on the Person model(So `'project_manager'` and `'project_collaborator'` is probably not the right choice. Maybe `'managing_projects'` and `'collaborating_projects'`? That would allow you to access a person's projects through `person.managing_projects` and `person.collaborating_projects`.
2. Is there only one project manager and collaborator on a project? In that case, you should use a ForeignKey instead of a ManyToManyField.
3. You can't do `self.project_manager + '&' + self.project_collaborator` because these fields don't have a way to be converted to a string. Instead (If you use ForeignKeys like I said in point 2, you should use `self.project_manager.name + '&' + self.project_collaborator.name`

Then finally instead of saving this field seperately in the database, you could use a @property decorator to generate this field on the fly:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_manager = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="managing_projects")
    project_collaborator = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="collaborating_projects")
    
    @property
    def project_info(self):
        return self.project_manager.name + '&' + self.project_collaborator.name
```

Comment: Hi Nico, thanks for the answer. About the point 2: I would like to design the database in the way that I can have one or more project managers (or generally speaking "people who are responsible for that project") and one or more collaborators ("people that collaborate on that project") for a project.

Comment: Then a many to ManyToManyField is ok, although you would need to traverse the set in project_info (Something like `for project_manager in self.project_managers.all()`)